# JS test framework that works with Deferreds/Promises

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jquery-deferred, promise, deferred

I am looking for a JavaScript test framework that natively works with [Deferreds/Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A).

That is: my test case functions will return a Deferred (e.g. [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or [whenjs](https://github.com/cujojs/when)) that when fires will yield `true` or `false` (success/failure).

A framework that only provides mechanisms to test specific async stuff like AJAX is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) can be easily patched to allow promises to be returned from `it` blocks. This is how we do it Montage: https://github.com/montagejs/montage/blob/master/test/support/spec-helper.js#L96-120. The spec is failed if the promise is rejected or is fulfilled with a value (not `undefined`). You can adapt it as needed.

Buster, another test framework, natively supports [specs returning promises](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/modules/buster-test/test-case/#id1).

Comment: Great, thanks for both hints! I check BusterJS .. looks nice and also claims headless and non-browser testing.